# Add value to parseInt object not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my javascript:

```
$('#vendorid').change(function(){
            var vendno = $(this).val();
            var data_String;
            var numpo = parseInt($('#numvendpo').val());
             data_String = 'vendorid='+vendno;
             $.post('ft-vendno.php',data_String,function(data){
                   var data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    $('#vendponum').val($('#vendponum').val() + data  +'-'+ numpo+1);
                });
            });
```

My output is:
[image]

As seen in the bottom textbox the last number "-31" should be "-4" (3+1). Whereas it is currently adding it as a string. I can't seem to figure out the problem though.

The top textbox is `#numvendpo` and the bottom is `#vendponum` forgive me for my confusing variable names.

Comment: you can check if the input is a number. `if(isNAN($value)===false) {// parse input}`

Comment: try adding numpo+1 into brackets (numpo+1). $('#vendponum').val($('#vendponum').val() + data  +'-'+ (numpo+1));

Comment: @SehaxX yup that was it my javascript knowledge still needs some work

Comment: @Jordan Here are some good example, also the complete site is great for learning and improving existing skills: https://javascript.info/operators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do:

```
some_string + numpo + 1
```

As the first value is a `string`, you are concatenating values from right to left, so you would first concatenate `numpo` (converting it to `string`) to `some_string`, and then `1`, also as a `string`.

You can fix that making sure the [operations are done in the right order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators), so one option might be to add parenthesis around `numpo + 1`:

```
$('#vendponum').val($('#vendponum').val() + data + '-' + (numpo + 1));
```

You can also do the sum before:

```
var numpo = parseInt($('#numvendpo').val()) + 1;
```

Or use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
$('#vendponum').val(`${ $('#vendponum').val() }${ data }-${ numpo + 1 }`);
```

Here you can see what works and what does not:

```js
const $vendorid = $('#vendorid');
const $numvendpo = $('#numvendpo');
const $outputParenthesis = $('#outputParenthesis');
const $outputBefore = $('#outputBefore');
const $outputTemplate = $('#outputTemplate');
const $outputWrong = $('#outputWrong');

$('#vendorid, #numvendpo').on('input', () => {
  const vendno = $vendorid.val();
  
  const numpo = parseInt($numvendpo.val());
  
  if (isNaN(numpo)) {
    return;
  }
  
  const numpoPlusOne = numpo + 1;

  $outputParenthesis.text(vendno + '-' + (numpo + 1));
  $outputBefore.text(vendno + '-' + numpoPlusOne);
  $outputTemplate.text(`${ vendno }-${ numpo + 1 }`);
  $outputWrong.text(vendno + '-' + numpo + 1);
});
```

```css
body,
input {
  font-family: monospace;
  
}

input {
  border: 3px solid black;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 200px;
}

p {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

.label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 222px;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 8px;
}

.wrong {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="Vendor ID" id="vendorid" type="text" />
<input placeholder="Num Vendor PO" id="numvendpo" type="text" />

<p><span class="label">WITH PARENTHESIS: </span><span id="outputParenthesis"></span></p>
<p><span class="label">SUM BEFORE: </span><span id="outputBefore"></span></p>
<p><span class="label">TEMPLATE LITERAL: </span><span id="outputTemplate"></span></p>
<p class="wrong"><span class="label">WRONG: </span><span id="outputWrong"></span></p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```